# Free up space by only deleting older photos past a chosen date

Tags: google-account, google-photos

Google photos app has a "free up space" option where it will delete all photos that have been already backed up to Google photos from the local device folders.

The problem with this is that the recent photos I need can be accessed faster so long as they are on the local device. Eg. No internet access needed unlike from Google photos.

Is there a way to only delete those photos (which have been backed up to Google photos) but are older than a certain date?

That way, say, photos more than a month old can be deleted ( this freeing up space) but the current photos stay available on the device  for me to use easily.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked into using an adb command for this yet? You could author a shell command like this one: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

Comment: I suppose you could make a point of connecting your Android to your computer and sitting down monthly to delete everything over a month old. This isn't the automated solution you or I would hope for, and maybe you've already rejected it as a bit too fiddly long-term, but it's the good enough one I'm using until I find something better.

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't achieve the goal. It will back up all photos to date while I want it to leave the most recent say 60 days on the device. I don't mind a manual solution but  I want to have the convenience of retaining the recent photos on the device

Answer (score 1):

Connect you phone to the computer via USB cable and use your favorite files management tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using an Android app for 4+ years called [Sweet Home WiFi Picture Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sweesoft.sweethome) that provides this functionality-- copies pictures to NAS, then allows delete if older than 3 months, but only after confirming the pictures exist on NAS.

However, recently, I've found that the photos on phone are not actually getting deleted (appears the app sees them as deleted, but the Android OS and file explorer show them as still there). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.